# Check for duplicate value

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an accordian with textfields. So you can add persons. And for each person you have a `textfield` where you can fill in  the email address. But a duplicate email address for different person is *not allowed*.

**For example:**

person A has email: hallo@gmail.com

person B has email: hallo@gmail.com NOT ALLOWED!!

I have this as javascript:

```
 $('#accordion .user-row').each(function (uindex, uvalue) {
                            html += '<tr>';

                            $(this).find('input').each(function (index, value) {

                                // Check if input type is a checkbox
                                if ($(this).is(":checkbox")) {
                                    var JaNee = 'Nee';
                                    if ($(this).is(":checked")) JaNee = 'Ja';
                                    html = html + '<td>' + JaNee + '</td>';
                                }
                                else {
                                    // Add the value into the html
                                    html = html + '<td>' + $(this).val() + '</td>';
                                }
                            });

                            html += '</tr>';
                        });
```

this is the html:

```
<div class="contact-label span2">
          <label for="contactpersonen-email">Email adres</label>
          <div class="contact-input-field">
            <input type="text" class="input-text span2" id="contactpersonen-email" name="contactpersonen-email"></input>
          </div>
        </div>
```

This is for generating the html fields:

```
$('#add-contact p a').click(function()
                                {
                                    // Make a copy of the first input fields
                                    html = $('#new-contact').children().clone();

                        // Get number of tabs in the accordion
                        var index = $('#accordion h3').length;

                                    // Remove the values
                                    html.find("input[type=text]").val("");
                  html.find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);

                        // New 'id', 'for' and 'name' attribute names
                        html.find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                            me = $(this);
                            attr = me.attr('id');
                            number = attr.split('_')[2];
                            newNumber = parseInt(index) + 1;
                            newAttr = attr.replace(number, newNumber);
                            me.attr('id', newAttr).attr('name', newAttr).next().attr('for', newAttr);
                        });                  

                                    // Insert it at the end
                        $('#accordion').append(html);
                        $('#accordion').accordion('refresh');

                        // Set last tab to active
                        $("#accordion").accordion({ active: index });

                                    // Cancel the click
                                    return false;
                                });
```

I have it now like this:

```
$('#add-contact p a').click(function()
                                {
                                     html = $('#new-contact').children().clone();                   
                                    // Make a copy of the first input fields
                                    var cnt = 0;
html.find('input[type=text]').each(function () {
         me = $(this);
         me.attr('id', 'contactpersonen-email-'+cnt);
         cnt++;


});
```

so I get:

contactpersonen-email
contactpersonen-email-2 so that is nice :)

but if I create a third textbox email. it is:

contactpersonen-email-2 so not unique.

you have:

contactpersonen-voornaam
contactpersonen-email..etc.

so by each new person, it has to be:
contactpersonen-voornaam1, contactpersonen-voornaam2..etc

and:

contactpersonen-email1, contactpersonen-email2..etc.

So I try it like this:

```
                            // Add extra contact clicked?
                                $('#add-contact p a').click(function()
                                {
var cnt = 0;
var cnt2 = 0;
var cnt3 = 0;
var cnt4 = 0;
var cnt5 = 0;
var cnt6 = 0;
          html = $('#new-contact').children().clone();                  
                                    // Make a copy of the first input fields

html.find('input[type=text]').each(function () {
         me = $(this);
         me.attr('id', 'contactpersonen-email-'+cnt);
         cnt++;


});

html.find('input[type=text]').each(function () {
         me = $(this);
         me.attr('id', 'contactpersonen-voornaam-'+cnt2);
         cnt2++;


});

html.find('input[type=text]').each(function () {
         me = $(this);
         me.attr('id', 'contactpersonen-achternaam-'+cnt3);
         cnt3++;


});

html.find('input[type=text]').each(function () {
         me = $(this);
         me.attr('id', 'contactpersonen-telefoon-'+cnt4);
         cnt4++;


});

html.find('input[type=text]').each(function () {
         me = $(this);
         me.attr('id', 'contactpersonen-functie-'+cnt5);
         cnt5++;


});

html.find('input[type=text]').each(function () {
         me = $(this);
         me.attr('id', 'contactpersonen-monteur-'+cnt6);
         cnt6++;


});






                        // Get number of tabs in the accordion
                        var index = $('#accordion h3').length;

                                    // Remove the values
                                    html.find("input[type=text]").val("");
                  html.find('input[type=checkbox]').attr('checked', false);

                        // New 'id', 'for' and 'name' attribute names
                        html.find('input[type=checkbox]').each(function () {
                            me = $(this);
                            attr = me.attr('id');
                            number = attr.split('_')[2];
                            newNumber = parseInt(index) + 1;
                            newAttr = attr.replace(number, newNumber);
                            me.attr('id', newAttr).attr('name', newAttr).next().attr('for', newAttr);
                        });                  

                                    // Insert it at the end
                        $('#accordion').append(html);
                        $('#accordion').accordion('refresh');

                        // Set last tab to active
                        $("#accordion").accordion({ active: index });

                                    // Cancel the click
                                    return false;
                                });
```

oke, I changed to this:

```
html.find('input[type=text]').each(function () {
         me = $('#contactpersonen-email');
         me.attr('id', 'contactpersonen-email-'+cnt);
         cnt++;    
});
```

but the problem now is that by the third added person, it still gives:
contactpersonen-email-1

and not but the problem now is that by the third added person, it still gives:
contactpersonen-email-2..etc

Comment: Please post HTML too. Partially workable fiddle link will be great.

Answer (score 1):

You can do like this:

```
$(function(){

$('input[name^="text"]').change(function() {

    var $current = $(this);

    $('input[name^="text"]').each(function() {
        if ($(this).val() == $current.val() && $(this).attr('id') != $current.attr('id'))
        {
            alert('duplicate email address. please enter another email address.');
            $current.val("");
        }

    });
  });
});


// for generating unique id example
var cnt = 0;
html.find('input[type=text]').each(function () {
         me = $(this);
         me.attr('id', 'contactpersonen-email-'+cnt);
         cnt++;
});
```

Comment: Why donw voted somebody my post?? What did I wrong then?

Comment: So I get answare for this?? Why somebody can down vote a post without any comment??? So everybody can do that without any reason. Is that not strange??? Sorry but this is realy unfair

Comment: But the id's are the same. And I can have two or three..four textboxes

Comment: Id should be unique for every textbox. Id can never be duplicated in html.

Comment: YOu can have a look at: http://webshop.verploegen.nl/klant-worden. THere you see that every id has the same value: contactpersonen-email

Comment: but its not the proper way. we can not access element using id in jquery if ids are duplicated.

Comment: if one textbox has id "id1" then another textbox should have "id2" like this we can make unique ids...

Comment: yes, I understand that. but so how to make them unique? Thank you

Comment: by setting counter value and increment it while generating html.

Comment: Can you give an example for this specific issue.

Comment: Multiple email textboxes are generated using jquery or it is generated using static html?

Comment: using javascript the textboxes are generated

Comment: I have edited post for generating unique ids for text inputs

Comment: but have you checked script? is it generating unique ids now in every textbox?

Comment: yes, but if you see in:http://webshop.verploegen.nl/klant-worden there are six textboxes and every textbox has to have unique id, like email

Comment: But anyway. If I do it for only email. the second time if you add a person, all the textboxes and not only the email will be overwritten with the email id

Comment: why are you looping through all text boxes multiple time with multiple counter variable? you need to loop through only once.

Comment: ok. But If I do it for just email, Then the counter starts counting by add person. Because textbox voornaam gets also: contactpersonen-email-0. What not has to be

Comment: ok so globally set unique id for every text box. or set email type (ex. type="email")in all input box in which email has be accepted and then loop through all email input box and add unique id into them.

Comment: Hi Dhara, but do you also have jsfiddle example of it. because I dont get a message when email address has an duplicate value